# What limits clone() from being accessible for all objects?

Tags: java

Why can't I access the `clone()` method for any object?
All objects extend `Object` and `clone` is in `Object` with the `protected` modifier. `protected` makes method accessible for subclasses. Why can't I access `clone`?

Comment: Are you trying to call `clone()` from a subclass, or from somewhere else? Seeing your code would help. See: [mre].

Comment: @JohnKugelman I think the issue is that because `clone` is declared in `Object`, technically every call to `clone` is from a subclass.

Comment: *"I do know that what I wrote above is wrong and ask you to correct me instead of downvoting."* - The downvotes are not because you were wrong.  They are because the question was not properly researched before asking.  Research that *should* have found the existing Q&A (and that its assumptions were wrong).  And it was a downvote on the question ... not on you.  (You will only get votes personally if you stand to be elected as a moderator!)  But since you asked to be corrected, this is me correcting you.

Comment: The primary purpose of votes on questions and answers is quality control on the Q&A knowledge-base.